# using promise in views in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, interpolation

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstName"><br>
Last Name: <input type="text" ng-model="lastName"><br>
<br>
Full Name: {{firstName + " " + lastName}}
{{obj}}

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope ,$q,$timeout) {
    $scope.firstName = "John";
    $scope.lastName = "Doe";
    var pro=function(){
var a=$q.defer();
$timeout(function(){
console.log("resolve");
a.resolve(1);
}, 
3000
);
    return a.promise;
}

$scope.obj=pro();

});
</script>
```

As i study when we use promise object in view it automatically adds resolve function to show the resolve value in view but it is not showing resolved value in view.it is just showing this "{}".what is wrong i am doing

Answer (score 0):

### Templates no longer automatically unwrap promises

`$parse` and templates in general will no longer automatically unwrap promises.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Migration from V1.0 to V1.2](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#templates-no-longer-automatically-unwrap-promises)